# gRPC client streaming taking much longer than server streaming, despite the client and server running on the same machine

Tags: c#, grpc, asp.net-core-6.0

I've implemented file uploading/downloading via gRPC, where the client is a console application and the server is an ASP.NET Core application. Uploading is implemented as a client-streaming RPC and downloading is implemented as a server-streaming RPC. The problem I'm having is that whenever I run both the client and the server on the same machine, it takes roughly 10 times as long to upload file x to the server file system as it does to download file x from the server file system (note that all of this is taking place on the hard drive of my machine).  The client upload (download) code is symmetric to the server download (upload) code. Here is the relevant snippet of the client upload code:

```
var clientStreamingCall = client.Upload();

// Now open the file-to-upload for reading
using (FileStream source = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(baseDir + @"\UploadFiles", fileName)))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;

    // write the file chunks to the requestStream
    while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        await clientStreamingCall.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new UploadRequest()
        {
            ChunkData = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(buffer),
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the server download code, which mirrors the above client upload code:

```
public override async Task Download(DownloadRequest request, IServerStreamWriter<DownloadResponse> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
{

    using (FileStream source = File.OpenRead(request.FilePath))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        // write the file chunks to the responseStream
        while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            await responseStream.WriteAsync(new DownloadResponse()
            {
                ChunkData = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(buffer),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Likewise, the client download code mirrors the server upload code; here is the client download code, which writes a chunk of the file-to-download in the response stream to the destination file (on the hard drive of my machine):

```
while (await serverStreamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(new CancellationToken()))
{
    dest.Write(serverStreamingCall.ResponseStream.Current.ChunkData.ToByteArray(), 0, serverStreamingCall.ResponseStream.Current.ChunkData.Length);
}
```

Here is the server upload code, which writes a chunk of the file-to-upload to the destination file (on the hard drive of my machine):

```
while (await requestStream.MoveNext())
{
    dest.Write(requestStream.Current.ChunkData.ToByteArray(), 0, requestStream.Current.ChunkData.Length);
}
```

Any idea as to why uploading takes so much longer than downloading, in spite of this symmetry?

Comment: To see what is the bottle neck, you should try "uploading" and "downloading" dummy data without really reading/writing to the disk and see if the behavior changes. Potentially this could be 1. problems with flow control in HTTP/2 (wrong window size) 2. serialization/deserialization problems 3. reading/writing to the disk

Comment: See DynamicWindowSizing feature added in .NET 6: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-6-networking-improvements/#http-2-window-scaling

Comment: @JanTattermusch Uniformly increasing the size of the buffer in both the client and server code appears to reduce the imbalance. Here's some data: For a fixed 92MB file, I get the following data: (1) Buffer size 1024 bytes: UL Time: 53 seconds, DL Time: 5 seconds (2) Buffer Size 10240 bytes: UL Time: 4304 ms, DL Time: 1706 ms (3) Buffer Size 20480 bytes: UL Time: 3376 ms, DL Time: 1229 ms. Still an imbalance, but not as pronounced.